# Sending array into view with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Good afternoon !

I have the following code and return the user correctly.

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
        $users = User::with('contacts')->get();
        foreach($users as $contact){
            foreach($contact->contacts as $contactos){
                if($contactos->pivot->estado==1){
                 $datos = ['pacientes' => $contactos->name];
                }

            }
        }
        return view('home',$datos);
```

I need to pass the results of $contactos into view , with this form I only can see the last item of array.

I have this in the view

```
{{$pacientes}}
```

but If I am use a foreach I receive the error undefined.

Could anyone helps me ?

**UPDATED**

Now , I have this code , If I use the var_dump($identifiers) I can see the ids I need , but now I don't know how to pass to User::find this two identifiers.

I receive the information about user correctly when I put $identifier[0] but I need a loop for this.

```
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $users = User::with('contacts')->get();
    $identifiers = [];
    foreach($users as $contact){
        foreach($contact->contacts as $contactos){
            if($contactos->pivot->estado==1){
                $identifiers[] =$contactos->pivot->user2 ;
            }

        }
    }
    $messageuser = User::whereIn('id', array($identifiers[0]))->get();
    return view('home')->with('contactos',$messageuser);
```

Comment: I update the question , I solve the problem in the view but now I have another question. :)

Comment: ask a new question. put your own answer and accept